# WebAudio - seamlessly playing sequence of audio chunks

Tags: javascript, html, streaming, web-audio-api

I have a live, constant source of waveform data that gives me a second of single-channel audio with constant sample rate every second. Currently I play them this way:

```js
// data : Float32Array, context: AudioContext
function audioChunkReceived (context, data, sample_rate) { 
    var audioBuffer = context.createBuffer(2, data.length, sample_rate);
    audioBuffer.getChannelData(0).set(data);
    var source = context.createBufferSource(); // creates a sound source
    source.buffer = audioBuffer;
    source.connect(context.destination);
    source.start(0);
}
```

Audio plays fine but with noticeable pauses between consecutive chunks being played (as expected). I'd like to get rid of them and I understand I'll have to introduce some kind of buffering.

**Questions:**

- Is there a JS library that can do this for me? (I'm in the process of searching through them)
- If there is no library that can do this, how should I do it myself?
- Detecting when playback finished in one source and have another one ready to play it immediately afterwards? (using AudioBufferSourceNode.onended event handler)
- Create one large buffer and copy my audio chunks one after another and control the flow using AudioBufferSourceNode.start AudioBufferSourceNode.stop functions?
- Something different?

Comment: Found project: https://github.com/scottstensland/websockets-streaming-audio which streams waveform files through websockets and it sounds decent: http://websockets-streaming-audio.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've written a small class in TypeScript that serves as buffer for now. It has **bufferSize** defined for controlling how many chunks it can hold. It's short and self-descriptive so I'll paste it here. There is much to improve so any ideas are welcome.

( you can quickly convert it to JS using: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/ )

```js
class SoundBuffer {
    private chunks : Array<AudioBufferSourceNode> = [];
    private isPlaying: boolean = false;
    private startTime: number = 0;
    private lastChunkOffset: number = 0;

    constructor(public ctx:AudioContext, public sampleRate:number,public bufferSize:number = 6, private debug = true) { }

    private createChunk(chunk:Float32Array)  {
        var audioBuffer = this.ctx.createBuffer(2, chunk.length, this.sampleRate);
        audioBuffer.getChannelData(0).set(chunk);
        var source = this.ctx.createBufferSource();
        source.buffer = audioBuffer;
        source.connect(this.ctx.destination);
        source.onended = (e:Event) => { 
            this.chunks.splice(this.chunks.indexOf(source),1);
            if (this.chunks.length == 0) {
                this.isPlaying = false;
                this.startTime = 0;
                this.lastChunkOffset = 0;
            }
        };

        return source;
    }

    private log(data:string) {
        if (this.debug) {
            console.log(new Date().toUTCString() + " : " + data);
        }
    }

    public addChunk(data: Float32Array) {
        if (this.isPlaying && (this.chunks.length > this.bufferSize)) {
            this.log("chunk discarded");
            return; // throw away
        } else if (this.isPlaying && (this.chunks.length <= this.bufferSize)) { // schedule & add right now
            this.log("chunk accepted");
            let chunk = this.createChunk(data);
            chunk.start(this.startTime + this.lastChunkOffset);
            this.lastChunkOffset += chunk.buffer.duration;
            this.chunks.push(chunk);
        } else if ((this.chunks.length < (this.bufferSize / 2)) && !this.isPlaying) {  // add & don't schedule
            this.log("chunk queued");
            let chunk = this.createChunk(data);
            this.chunks.push(chunk);
        } else  { // add & schedule entire buffer
            this.log("queued chunks scheduled");
            this.isPlaying = true;
            let chunk = this.createChunk(data);
            this.chunks.push(chunk);
            this.startTime = this.ctx.currentTime;
            this.lastChunkOffset = 0;
            for (let i = 0;i<this.chunks.length;i++) {
                let chunk = this.chunks[i];
                chunk.start(this.startTime + this.lastChunkOffset);
                this.lastChunkOffset += chunk.buffer.duration;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Man, I spent days looking for it. Thank you very much

Comment: I'm still getting tiny (<0.15s) gaps in between each chunk, which becomes noticeable once the chunks are relatively small (<0.3s). I'm thinking this may have to do with the leading and ending edges of the chunks being orphaned (or corrupted) of their mp3 headers, but I'm not sure how to amend that.

Comment: Still getting 6 millisecond delays

Comment: Can you show how to use your class with MediaRecoder data?

Answer (score 6):

You don't show how `audioChunkReceived`, but to get seamless playback, you have to make sure you have the data before you want to play it and *before* the previous one stops playing.

Once you have this, you can schedule the newest chunk to start playing when the previous one ends by calling start(t), where t is the end time of the previous chunk.

However, if the buffer sample rate is different from the context.sampleRate, it's probably not going to play smoothly because of the resampling that is needed to convert the buffer to the context rate.

Comment: Thank you, I've used your advice and pieced together simple solution. You can view it in another answer. If I had more karma I'd upvote your answer :)

Answer (score -1):

I think it is because you allocate your buffer for 2 channel. 
change that to one.

```
context.createBuffer(2, data.length, sample_rate);
```

to

```
context.createBuffer(1, data.length, sample_rate);
```